# How to correctly check if a string is equal to another string in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am looking for better ways to check if two strings are equal in Clojure!

Given a map 'report' like

```
{:Result Pass}
```

, when I evaluate

```
(type (:Result report))
```

I get : `Java.Lang.String`

To write a check for the value of `:Result`, I first tried

```
(if (= (:Result report) "Pass") (println "Pass"))
```

But the check fails.

So I used the compare method, which worked:

```
(if (= 0 (compare (:Result report) "Pass")) (println "Pass"))
```

However, I was wondering if there is anything equivalent to Java's `.equals()` method in Clojure. Or a better way to do the same.

Comment: Please verify what you posted as Pass isn't a String in `{:Result Pass}`. Even if it was, the code you have should work and should be equivalent to the last bit of code. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: `(def r {:Result "Pass"})` `(if (= (:Result r) "Pass") (println "Pass"))` successfully prints "Pass" fine. Please try it again, as the code is fine.

Comment: The question I posted is verified, the map is an xml response I get from hitting an API server, which does in fact look like {:Result Pass}, and with the type 'Java.Lang.String' . I agree that it should have worked, but oddly it does not, and also that 'Pass' in report looks like it is not a string.

Comment: You must have hidden characters in the String or something. `=` is fine for comparing Strings. Try `(vec (:Result report))` to see if there's any whitespace that you're missing. I suspect theres a newline at the end or something.

Comment: You have verified that the variable `Pass` holds a string.  But what is its *contents*?

Comment: If the map is a result of some other call did you maybe use `println` to get at its value? That suppresses the double quotes of a string. As others said before, using `=` to compare strings is correct. There's something else going on in your code.

Comment: Everyone is justifiably skeptical of your claims that your data is correct as posted, because you keep claiming `type` returns `Java.Lang.String`, when this cannot be true: it can only return `java.lang.String`. Please copy and paste your input *exactly*, rather than paraphrasing them.

Comment: @amalloy I appreciate your concern, but paraphrasing the question does not change the question since I only changed the names 'report' and 'pass' and 'result'.

Comment: @StefanKamphausen Thanks a ton! I see now, I was using print to print the value, which suppressed the double quotes as well as the "\n" for newline.

Comment: @Carcigenicate There were trailing whitespaces + newline ("\n") which I could not see at first. Using prn instead of print helped. Thank you, being a noob clojurian I really appreciate the help.!!

Comment: @SnehaaGanesan Glad to help. That's why it's always important to check your data and to have proper representative [mcve]s here when posting though, especially when commentors have indicated that the code is fine as posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Carcigenicate wrote, use `=` to compare strings.

```clj
(= "hello" "hello")
;; => true
```

If you want to be less strict, consider normalizing your string before you compare. If we have a leading space, the strings aren't equal.

```clj
(= " hello" "hello")
;; => false
```

We can then define a normalize function that works for us.
In this case, ignore leading and trailing whitespace and
capitalization.

```
(require '[clojure.string :as string])

(defn normalize [s]
  (string/trim
    (string/lower-case s)))

(= (normalize " hellO")
   (normalize "Hello\t"))
;; => true
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

`=` is the correct way to do an equality check for Strings. If it's giving you unexpected results, you likely have whitespace in the String like a trailing newline.

You can easily check for whitespace by using `vec`:

```
(vec " Pass\n")

user=> [\space \P \a \s \s \newline]
```